# jQuery reuse selector and manipulate items

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection

I want to select all the elements of a certain class and then manipulate them as the page runs. I don't want to have to continually query for the same set of items, but I do need to access different elements. Here's what I mean:

```
var items = $(".these"); // The items I need to use
items.first().hide() // Hide the first item

$(".these:nth-child(3)"); // How could I get the third element of items and perform jQuery functions on them without querying again?

items[3].hide() // Doesn't work because the third element isn't accessed with jQuery.
```

I need to be able to do this with an index. For instance, right now I'm doing this:

```
$(".these:nth-child(" + index + ")");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use th eq() function 
http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks for such a simple solution!

Interesting note - when using nth-child, the first element is element 1, but when using eq(), the first element is element 0.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery recommends the functions to selectors. ;-)

Comment: this acts more like :nth-of-type. It only works if the children of the parent are the same selector.

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
var items = $('.these');
items.find(':nth-child(3)').hide();
```

Comment: No, that will find the third child among child elements of the items, not the item which is a third-child of it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for the the `.filter()` function in jQuery.  See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
e.g.

```
items.filter(':nth-child(3)').hide();
```

Or, as already suggested, eq if you only want to go after a certain index.  Filter can take any jQuery selector however.  E.g.

```
items.filter(':visible:first')
```

to find the first one still visible after the earlier manipulation.

Comment: Interesting. I used the eq() solution and it worked great. Do you know the difference between filter and eq? Is filter just more broad and allow you different ways to filter while eq is strictly index-based?

Comment: Pretty much.  Have added another example for filter